# Method to create custom drop shadow for a WPF button

Tags: wpf, xaml

How would I go about creating the drop shadow that is shown below for a WPF button (or a Border, etc)? The drop shadow is "curved" and is thicker on the ends and thinner in the middle. I'd like to avoid using images (PNG) if possible, but if that is the best option then so be it. Is there a way to do it using gradients instead somehow?

[image: example button]

Comment: Since this probably isn't much help because I don't the exact path definitions, I'll add it as a comment...I have read that some people draw custom drop shadowing using geometry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you'll have to edit the default `Template` for the `Button` and add a `Shape` that you add the `DropShadowEffect` to. An even better approach is to create a custom control which derives from `Button` that has this `Template` Then you could add Dependency Properties for the values that you would like to be able to configure, like `ShadowDepth`, `BlurRadius`, Angle for the Arc etc.

Here is an example. It requires a reference to **PresentationFramework.Aero**.

[image]

```
<Style x:Key="BottomArcShadowButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       xmlns:MS_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <MS_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </MS_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <Path Grid.ZIndex="-1"
                          Stroke="Green"
                          StrokeThickness="6"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          Fill="Green"
                          StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                          StrokeStartLineCap="Square"
                          Data="M0,0 L1,0 L1,1 A1,1 180 0 0 0,1 L0,0">
                        <Path.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="15"
                                              Direction="270"
                                              Color="Black"
                                              Opacity="0.5"
                                              BlurRadius="4"/>
                        </Path.Effect>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That worked great. I never thought of using the drop shadow effect in combination with a path. awesome!

Comment: Very nice! +1 (deserves more though)